# setFetchBatchSize on a NSFetchRequest on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I don't understand the meaning of setFetchBatchSize.

In the following code, I set the fetch batch size to 20, but I still get 49 objects in my results array (which are ALL the objects from the query)

```
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"company.id = %@", company.id];
        NSFetchRequest *req = [CategoryEntity requestAllSortedBy:@"id" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate];
        [req setFetchBatchSize:20];
        NSArray *results = [CategoryEntity executeFetchRequest:req];
```

So what's the meaning of setFetchBatchSize, since it doesn't seem to limit the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To limit the size use fetchLimit.

With batch size, the objects are faulted. They look like they are there but those are just stubs. When you access them - behind the scenes - the values are then populated.

Comment: Thanks... It Took me like 6 - 7 Posts to get to this Simple Solution.... Cheers ;-)